# Find rotated polynomials

Tags: combinatorics

Let $ B_{m,n}(x,y) $ be  polynomials with the followimg  property

$$
\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty B_{m,n}(x \cos\theta-y \sin\theta,x \sin\theta +y \cos\theta)  \frac{u^m}{m!}  \frac{v^n}{n!}=\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty B_{m,n}(x,y) \frac{ (u \cos\theta {+} v \sin\theta)^m}{m!}  \frac{(v\cos\theta {-}u \sin\theta)^n}{n!}. 
$$
In other words  we have

$$
\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty R_{\theta}( B_{m,n}(x,y))  \frac{u^m}{m!}  \frac{v^n}{n!}=\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty B_{m,n}(x,y) R_{-\theta}\left(\frac{u^m}{m!}  \frac{v^n}{n!}\right ),
$$

where $R_{\theta}$ is usual plane rotation acting on the variables $(x,y)$ and $(u,v).$

**Question.** Find explicit expression for $R_\theta(B_{m,n}(x,y))$.

By long brute force (expanding powers and equating the coefficients)  I have got the expression

$$
 R_\theta(B_{m,n}(x,y))=\sum_{j=0}^m \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{j} \binom{m}{j} \binom{n}{k}  (\cos \theta)^{m-j+k} (\sin \theta)^{n-k+j} B_{m+n-j-k, j+k}(x,y)
$$
but I hope there is more elegant way to get the  result.

Thank you.